# How can I have multiple arguments in a command (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I cant get a lot of arguments, I was trying to make an embed generator so I can send embeds right away without having to debug it over and over.

```py
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
     embed=discord.Embed(title="{}".format(arg1), description="{}".format(arg2), color=0xff0000)
     embed.set_author(name="{}".format(arg3))
     embed.add_field(name="{}".format(arg4), value="{}".format(arg5), inline=True)
     embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: This should work what you got here @AidanProgramizz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With commands, you can have as many positional arguments as you want. Each value separated by a space will be passed to the command function as a positional argument. (When invoking the command, quote the input to pass an argument which contains a space.) Command functions can only take one keyword-only argument. On invocation, any input that is not passed to the function as a positional argument is passed as a keyword argument.

---

```py
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx, title, description, author, name, value):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc)
    embed.set_author(name=author)
    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

---

For your command (which only has positional arguments), everything should work fine. A sample invocation:

`!embed Title "This is a sample description" Author Name "Field value which corresponds to 'name'"`

For this invocation, the arguments of `embed()` would be as follows:

- `title="Title"`
- `description="This is a sample description"`
- `author="Author"`
- `name="Name"`
- `value="Field value which corresponds to 'name'"`

Note that all positional arguments must be passed on invocation, otherwise an error is thrown. This can be avoided by setting default values to each argument (e.g. `async def embed(ctx, title="Embed Title", ...)`)

---

Check out the documentation for the [`discord.ext.commands` framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#).